# How to return char** to ctypes with malloc

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I've been trying to return a char** array into my Python code via ctypes.  I have a way that "works", but I don't like it as I have to have some extra code on the Python side.  I have to believe this is possible.

My Python code:

```py
from ctypes import *

strarray = POINTER(c_char_p)

getStr = cdll.context.getStrings
getStr.argtypes = [c_char_p, strarray]

fname = b"test.ctx"

names = strarray()

int numStrs = getStr(fname, names)

for i in range(numStrs):
    print(names[i])
```

My C/C++ code:

```c
int getStrings(char* fname, char **names)
{
    int count;
    int strSize;
    count = getNameCount();
    names = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::string name = getName(i);
        strsize = name.length() + 1;
        *names = (char*) malloc(strsize *sizeof(char));
        strcpy_s(*parts, strsize, name.c_str());
        *names++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

When I try to print out the `names` in Python, I get `ValueError: NULL pointer access`.

As I said, I have something that kind of works.  In the Python, if I don't use `POINTER(c_char_p)` but specify some amount of pointers like `c_char_p*4096` and remove the `malloc` from the C code, I can get the results just fine.  Ideally, though, I would like to allocate the memory on the C side.  I feel like there is some subtlety that I am missing.

I'm using Python 3.5.2, in case that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
names = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
```

assigns memory to `names` but the caller in Python will not see this. For that, use:

```
*names = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);
```

It means you must declare the function as:

```
int getStrings(char* fname, char ***names)
```

a triple indirection.

I don't know what you need to change in Python, but at least you must pass the address of the Python `names` variable.

The correct C (C++) code is:

```
int getStrings(char* fname, char ***names)
{
    int count;
    int strSize;
    count = getNameCount();
    *names = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        std::string name = getName(i);
        strsize = name.length() + 1;
        (*names)[i] = (char*) malloc(strsize *sizeof(char));
        strcpy_s((*names)[i], strsize, name.c_str());
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I was struggling to get my head around the problem, but this makes perfect sense.  Thanks!